# Why is my animated character sliding left?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using a simple clearInterval draw animation to animate a spritesheet. I have two animations and have set the canvas size the same for both. I have checked the width of the spritesheet to make sure it's correct. For some reason the animation executes but my character slides left and part of the next frame becomes visible before starting the animation over. I've checked over and over for bugs. Hopefully just missed something easy. Here is my code. Spritesheet with issue is posted in a link at the bottom of post. Thank you so much.

```js
// QUIZGAME ANIMATION

var canvasWidth = 200;
var canvasHeight = 250;
var canvas2Height = 250;
var canvas2Width = 200;

var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  canvas1.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas1.height = canvasHeight;
  canvas2.height = canvas2Height;
  canvas2.width = canvas2Width;
});

var spriteWidth = 605;
var spriteHeight = 200;

var sprite2Width = 1632;
var sprite2Height = 200;


var columns = 3;
var rows = 1;
var columns2 = 11;
var rows2 = 1;

var width = spriteWidth / columns;
var height = spriteHeight / rows;
var height2 = sprite2Height / rows2;
var width2 = sprite2Width / columns2;

var curFrame = 0;
var curFrame2 = 0;

var frameCount = 3;
var frameCount2 = 11;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var y2 = 0;

var frameX = 0;
var frameY = 0;
var frameX2 = 0;
var frameY2 = 0;

var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

var character = new Image();
var character2 = new Image();

character.src = "img/testanimation.png";
character2.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uRCO.png";

function changeFrameIndex() {
  curFrame = ++curFrame % frameCount;
  frameX = curFrame * width;
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
}

function changeFrame2Index() {
  curFrame2 = ++curFrame2 % frameCount2;
  frameX2 = curFrame2 * width2;
  ctx2.clearRect(x2, y2, width2, height2);
}

function draw() {
  //Updating the frame 
  changeFrameIndex();
  //Drawing the image 
  ctx.drawImage(character, frameX, frameY, width, height, x, y, width, height);
}

function draw2() {
  changeFrame2Index();
  ctx2.drawImage(character2, frameX2, frameY2, width2, height2, x2, y2, width2, height2);
}

//setInterval(draw, 140); // disabled by editor because source is unavailable
setInterval(draw2, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

[spritesheet with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uRCO.png)

I have partially resolved the issue but I'm still a little confused. I cropped some empty space off the end of the spritesheet (making sprite2Width = 1604 instead of the original 1632) which helped, reducing the motion to next to none, but for some reason I still have to clarify a width that is 4-6 px shorter than the actual png. The animation is working now after cropping spritesheet width at 1604px and setting the sprite2Width = 1598; (as opposed to 1604). Anyone have any idea why there is a 6 px difference here? CSS related maybe? Atleast it is working.

Comment: If the spritesheets are small, and **you own them** (they are not ripped from a game), please post those as well so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: They are pulled from opengameart website so they should be open for use as long as credit is given to the author which it will be. I will post the spritesheet thank you.

Comment: @zero298 ok the image should be posted under a link in the original post "spritesheet with issue" Thank you so much

Comment: not sure where you got your spriteWidth and columns numbers, but if you change to `var width = 147;` does that work for you?

Comment: @AndrewLohr https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/javascript-sprite-animation-tutorial-html5-canvas/ this is the tutorial that i was attempting to follow. I was under the impression spriteWidth would be the total width of the sprite sheet divided by the number of columns (or frames i guess) in this case 11. If you could clear up the logic for me that would be so appreciated. When i changed the width to 145 it kept the character in place and the animation ran. part of the previous frame is showing on the left side but it fixed the major issue.

Comment: it looks like the sprites are all the same in that sheet, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I rolled back your edit because having it visually in the question is not useful. What may be is to have it downloadable so we can further analyze it.

Comment: @AndrewLohr the sprite sheet was labeled idle I pulled it from a larger spritesheet by cropping. The character is just supposed to stand there and slightly bounce maybe that's why they look the same to you. After changing the width to 145 I got the desired effect. Character bounces and does not move side to side at all. Earlier it looked like it was trying to scroll the whole sprite to the side a bit. Where did you get the 147 figure. 147 got close to fixing it. I came up with sprite2Width by dividing tota pixell width entire sheet by number of columns (11).

Comment: I have partially resolved the issue but I'm still a little confused. I cropped some empty space off the end of the spritesheet (making sprite2Width = 1604 instead of the original 1632) which helped, reducing the motion to next to none, but for some reason I still have to clarify a width that is 4-6 px shorter than the actual png. The animation is working now after cropping spritesheet width at 1604px and setting the sprite2Width = 1598; (as opposed to 1604). Anyone have any idea why there is a 6 px difference here? CSS related maybe? Atleast it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do when troubleshooting something like that is simplify your code...

Take it to the bare basic, then start playing with the variables that build each frame, yes like you find out there is a 6px padding on each sprite, you can compensate that on code see the calculation of the width.

```js
var character = new Image();
character.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uRCO.png";

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var spriteWidth = 1632;
var columns = 11;

var width = (spriteWidth / columns) - 3;
var curFrame = 0;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
  curFrame = ++curFrame % columns;
  ctx.drawImage(character, curFrame * width, 0, width, 200, 0, 0, width, 200);
}

setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=175></canvas>
```

...and for the record that sprite is not the best looking one

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful as you provided some context and I  attempted to subtract from the width value before to compensate but didn't have the syntax quite right I left out the parentheses. I know now though that my thinking behind the problem was correct. Just learning as much as I can every day, I'm still fairly new to JavaScript. I really appreciate your time. Do the 900 values represent the destination x and y values?

Comment: @LarryYoung the 900 in the `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 900, 900);` is just something big to clear the entire canvas, I could have used  9999 just something bigger than your canvas, comes useful when troubleshooting sprites and less variables to worry about

Comment: oh okay that clears it up. Perfect thank you! Have a great day and thanks again!